# Java heartbeat design

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, heartbeat

I need to implement a heartbeat system on my Java project (3-5 Clients with 1 server for them) but I have some questions.

1) Do I need to have 2 sockets by clients ? 1 for the heartbeat and 1 to receive normal message for my software

2) I saw that in specific case when a client is lagging, the client don't receive a message, how to avoid this ?

3) In case of a client disconnect, how to retreive the connection with it ? Without recreate a new socket with it.

Comment: Do you need to do it from scratch or can you use a already implemented external library?

Comment: From scratch to learn how it works

Comment: I've been working on a medium-sized project that has a really good heartbeat mechanism. I'll write an answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, you have a "central server" which needs to provide an heartbeat mechanism to the clients. Well, part of the solution is simple since you have only 1 server, which simplifies a LOT since you don't need to deal with data replication, data synchronization mechanisms, server failure, and so on. You just expect that your server never fails and if it fails it's a **fatal** error.

My suggestion is to implement a system based on notifications (pooling is bad and ugly): instead of having the server pooling the clients, you have the **clients reporting to the server** every X seconds of their state. This reduces the general overload of your system and it's based on the design principle of "[Tell, don't ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)". This also allows you to have different report times for each individual client.

There is one more question, which is what data do you want to transmit? Simply if the client is alive? Runtime data of the client, for example, % of it's job done if the client is downloading a file? Environment status, such as CPU overload, memory usage, network status? Define that, that's the first step.

Talking about the java implementation, you should run your a thread on each of your clients (implementing the Runnable interface). It should look something like this code (this is simplified for the sake of brevity):

```
public class HeartbeatAgent implements Runnable {

private int DEFAULT_SAMPLING_PERIOD = 5; //seconds
private String DEFAULT_NAME = "HeartbeatAgent";
private HashMap<Integer, Object> values; // <id, value>


public HeartbeatAgent () {
  values = new HashMap<Integer,Object>();

}


private void collect() {
    /** Here you should collect the data you want to send 
        and store it in the hash
    **/

}

public void sendData(){
    /** Here you should send the data to the server. Use REST/SOAP/multicast messages, whatever you want/need/are forced to **/
}

public void run() {
  System.out.println("Running " +  DEFAULT_NAME );
  try {
     while( /** condition you want to stop **/ {
        System.out.println("Thread: " + DEFAULT_NAME + ", " + "I'm alive");

        this.collect();
        this.send();
        // Let the thread sleep for a while.
        Thread.sleep(DEFAULT_SAMPLING_PERIOD * 1000);
     }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println("Thread " +  DEFAULT_NAME + " interrupted.");
 }
 System.out.println("Thread " +  DEFAULT_NAME + " exiting.");
}
}
```

You should write a server that handles the requests made and is "smart" enough to call a time-out after X seconds without "news" from client Y.

This is still not ideal, since you collect data and send it with the same sampling period, but usually you want to collect data at very tiny intervals (collecting CPU usage every 5 seconds, for instance) but only report it every 30 seconds.

If you want to look at good code of a good library that does this (it's what we've been using to our project at my company), take a look at [JCatascopia](https://github.com/CELAR/cloud-ms/) framework code (just look at the Agent and Server folders, ignore the others).

There's a lot to say about this topic, this is the basic. Feel free to ask!

Comment: Oh, thank you ! the queue system is a very good idea. But, I don't see how we can know that a client was disconnect ? Is it with the timeout system ?

Comment: Yes. If the server knows that client X sends a keep-alive message each 30 seconds (for instance), if the server fails to receive any message after 90 seconds (usually you wait 3 retries), the client disconnected. You can also implement a message that says "disconnect" and informs the server that client X disconnected. There are plenty of ways to do it. You need to understand what fits best your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to implement it and keep it somewhere on my computer for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to take a look at this small framework I made for a project I'd worked one last year. It's focused on a simple implementation and yet a strong feedback about your clients status.

It's based on UDP protocol which sends a payload containg an id, which it can be a MAC address of a NIC or an id chosen and set automatically by you or something else too, that confirms the client being safe and sound.

I think it's kind of cool because it's based on listeners which then receive various kinds of events based on what the heartbeat protocol compute about a client status.

You can find more about it [here](https://github.com/Daniele-Comi/HeartbeatProtocol)

I think it's handy to use it with TCP sockets to understand if you are capable or not to send data over your TCP stream. Having continuos feedback on your clients status takes you in a position where you can easily achieve that, for example by saving in some sort of map your client status and check it before sending any kind of data.